# Display custom post term or taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called 'rent', inside that custom post type I've assigned some taxonomies like building1, building2 etc, inside that taxonomies I have some terms.

Let's say I have a custom rent post in taxonomy building1 with term 1stfloor.
I'd like to output on that post single page a term name and slug.
I've could have easily done that using `get_post_terms` or something similar, but that function requires to specify taxonomy. But I would have many taxonomies for that custom post, and I don't want to make another single.php for every taxonomy.

So I thought I would somehow get the taxonomy of my post (it will always be one taxonomy), assign it to variable, and put as an arg to `get_post_term`s. Well you can simply achieve taxonomy of current post using  `get_post_terms`

In my archive page I used `$taxname = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );` - which works like a charm, but it is not working on custom post single.

Anyone have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a couple specific examples? Also, it sounds like a hierarchical taxonomy may be a better fit with buildings as parent terms of floors [as the child terms]. The one `get_the_terms()` solves it all.

Comment: Well, I've used your suggestion :) I had to take some more steps to make it work like earlier, but it seems it was the solution :)

Thanks!

Comment: you should write up an answer to your question and accept it or I can write up my recommendations as an answer. Former is preferred to the latter in this case, I think.

Comment: Write your recommendations please, you need a credit for solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, it seems the multiple taxonomies have a clear hierarchical relationship.

Rather than a unique taxonomy for building 1, building 2, etc., these can all be located in a single "Buildings" taxonomy that is **hierarchical** like this:

- **Buildings Taxonomy:**

  - Building 1

    - Floor 1
    - Floor 2
    - Floor 3
  - Building 2

    - Floor 1
    - etc.

This means that there's only ever one taxonomy to query with `get_terms()`. As a bonus, it makes it easy to final all posts on all floors in Building 1 or all floors in Building 2.